# Get a tweet by ID in JavaScript with twit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I'm using [twit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit) in Node to stream tweets, and I want to use setTimeout to grab each tweet 5 minutes after it's posted (to see how many likes it's gotten in those 5 minutes.

I have the streaming and timeout working fine, but now I need to [re-fetch the status](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/show/:id) from Twitter to get the updated like count. So within the timeout I'll do:

```
T.get('statuses/show/:id', { id: statusId }, function(err, data, response) {
  console.log('test err     : ' + err )
  console.log('test data    : ' + data
  console.log('test response: ' + response )
})
```

where `statusId` is the ID from the streamed tweet. This fails, because Twitter ID's are 18-digit numbers, which JavaScript rounds! I have the ID as a string, but the [Twitter API point](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/show/:id) wants a number. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I do not think you should provide the `statusId` as a number. The call should work fine when you provide the `statusId` as a string.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I *had* tried that, but I got back `[object Object]` and I didn't realize that was actually successful. `data.text` and all that works.